# Pass parameter/argument to axios interceptor

Tags: javascript, axios

How do I send custom parameters to the *axios* interceptor? I am using an interceptor like this:

```
window.axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    if (PASSED_PARAM == true) {
        doSomethingAwesome();
    }

    return config;
}, function (error) {    
    return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

I also have a response interceptor that needs to receive the same parameter.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The method suggested by @Laurent will cause axios to wipe out all your other parameters and replace it with `my_variable`, which is may not exactly what you want.

The proper way of **adding** default parameters instead of **replacing** it is like this:

```
axios.defaults.params = {};
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    config.params['blah-defaut-param'] = 'blah-blah-default-value';
    return config;
}, function (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

This works with axios `0.18.1`. It does not work with axios `0.19` due to a regression  bug..., I believe it will be fixed soon.

Comment: I feel like all the suggested solutions don't solve the actual question. I think the question is not about adding params inside the interceptor, but adding options/arguments when calling e.g. `axios.get()` which are available inside the interceptor (but ideally not send to the server). So the interceptor can distinguish between requests and adjust it's behavior accordingly.

Comment: @John, were you able to figure this out ?

Comment: @Sathish this answer by Tomek C suggests a quite simple solution - although I haven't tried it myself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67823650/5025424

Comment: This doesn't answer the OPs question, I found it looking to solve the same. Ended up digging through axios source and came up with what I believe is the actual answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70647045/822223

Answer (score 30):

Merge params

```
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  config.params = {...config.params, my_variable: 'value'}
  return config
})
```

Answer (score 17):

The accepted answer, and the answers on this page seem to have missed what the question is asking.

This question is asking something like "When I call axios can I pass data to the interceptor but not to the server" and the answer is yes. Though it is undocumented and when using typescript you'll have to add a //@ts-ignore.

When you call axios you can pass a config object, (either after the url, or if you're not using a shortcut method like .get/.post the axios function just takes a config object. The good news is that config object is always passed along with the response so you can get to it in the interceptor and in the promise handers.

its available on the response objects as `response.config` and on the error as `error.response.config`

```
//@ts-ignore -- typescript will complain that your param isn't expected on the config object.
axios({
    method: "get",
    url: '/myapi/gocrazy',
    // just piggyback any data you want to the end of config, just don't
    // use any key's that axios is already expecting
    PASSED_PARAM: true
}

//in the interceptor, config is attached to the object, and it keeps any extra keys you tacked on the end.

window.axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
   if (config.PASSED_PARAM == true) {
    doSomethingAwesome();
   }

   return config;
   }, function (error) {
   
   return Promise.reject(error);
});

window.axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
   if (response.config.PASSED_PARAM == true) {
    doSomethingAwesome();
   }

   return response;
   }, function (error) {
   
   if (error.response.config.PASSED_PARAM == true) {
    doSomethingElseAwesome();
   }

   return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

Answer (score 9):

## Working solution

It's actually fairly simple to add parameters to the query with Axios interceptors when you send data.

```
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  config.params = {my_variable: 'value'}
  return config
})
```

Comment: Isn't this wiping out anything that exists on params?

Answer (score 9):

axios allows to pass some additional request parameters:

```
axios.post('/api', `some body`,
    {headers: {'Content-Type': ' text/html;charset=UTF-8'},
    param: true});
```

and interceptor:

```
 this.axios.interceptors.request.use(req => {   
    console.log(`${req.method}: ${req.param}`); //output: `/api: true`
    return req;
    });
```

I have tested it on version: 0.21.1

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the `headers` object. Not sure if that is recommended, or if it's anti-pattern. But anyhow it works. I am not entirely sure about how many bytes the header adds to the server request head, but I think it's neglectable.

Comment: I was also wondering how to pass parameters and don't want to end up with headers ... If you have alternative solution ?

Comment: Can you please submit a code example. i am having the exact same problem and not sure where and how to insert this param via header

Comment: how did you do it? I tried to set a header on the request interceptor and retrieve it on the response interceptor but it doesn't work; axios complains about header cannot be set after sending to client

Comment: You should use the solution @Laurent supplied: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48262327/5191800

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer from [DiamondDrake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/822223/diamonddrake?tab=profile), the global typings can be overridden to not have to 'ts-ignore' the usage:

```
declare module 'axios' {
    interface AxiosRequestConfig extends OriginalAxiosRequestConfig {
        PASSED_PARAM: boolean;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer of https://stackoverflow.com/users/12706095/zack is kinda correct.

You should create an axios.d.ts file including the following lines, the rest is done by TypeScript.

```
import "axios";

declare module "axios" {
    export interface AxiosRequestConfig {
        /** A custom axios request config param that can be used anywhere now. */
        myParam?: boolean;
     }
 }
```

Now TypeScript won't bother you anymore when you want to use this custom property anywhere when accessing the AxioRequestConfig, e.g. your interceptor.

See [Axios typescript customize AxiosRequestConfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58777924/axios-typescript-customize-axiosrequestconfig) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass param but you can update the passed param `config`. request interceptor logic runs before executing requests. It is kinda middlewares So maybe you need to access to tokens and update the request headers

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    // or maybe you need to read the stored cookies
    const user = localStorage.getItem("user");   
    if (user) {
      // If user exists get the token
      const token = JSON.parse(user).token;
      // and then update the headers
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }   
    // maybe u need to refresh the access tokens, you do it in interceptor
    return config;
  },
  (err) => {
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, just pass parameter in config and detect it inside of the interceptor.request. I found i pretty easy to use, code below.

Interceptor:

```
const XDEBUG_SESSION = "XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM";
axiosHttpClient.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    if (config.XDEBUG === true) {
        if (config.url.includes("?")) {
            config.url = config.url + "&" + XDEBUG_SESSION;
        } else {
            config.url = config.url + "?" + XDEBUG_SESSION;
        }
    }
    return config;
});
```

Usage:

```
     axiosHttpClient
        .get(APP_FETCH_PATHS.userPrivileges + 414, {
            XDEBUG: true,
        })
        .then((r) => console.log(r));
```

Answer (score 0):

after countering this issue, I've found out that there is no way to pass the parameter among the request configs.

so I've used the URL to pass the parameter, and then removing it before executing the request,

In my case it was a boolean parameter, so in the file that contains the request configs:

```
import request from '@/utils/request'
    
export function fetchIndex() {
    return request({
    url: 'client/mqtt/?no_alert', // (1) here we added the no_alert message
    method: 'get'
  })
}
```

in the @/utils/request.js we initiated the Axios request, and we added the no_alert verification.

```
import axios from 'axios'

var alert = true

// create an axios instance
const service = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_API,
  timeout: 5000 // request timeout
})

// request interceptor
service.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
    if (config.url.includes("?noalert")) { // (2) here we check if the message is exist 
      alert = false // editing the alert variable to is it in response after the request is done
      config.url = config.url.replace('?noalert', ''); // (3) here we recleared the url
    }
    return config
  }
)

// response interceptor
service.interceptors.response.use(
  response => {
    var res = response.data
    if (response.status !== 200) {
      if (alert) {  // (4 finally) then we use the alert var created before and modified depending on the no_alert parameter.
        doSomething()
      }
      return res
    }
  }
)

export default service
```