# Axios typescript customize AxiosRequestConfig

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, axios

I am using React and Axios. Recently, I have created a custom config on Axios like this:

```
import $axios from 'helpers/axiosInstance'
$axios.get('/customers', { handlerEnabled: false })
```

but the resulting TS compilation:

> Argument of type '{ handlerEnabled: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AxiosRequestConfig'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'handlerEnabled' does not exist in type 'AxiosRequestConfig'.

How can I assign new types on `AxiosRequestConfig`?
something like this `axios<AxiosRequestConfig & newType>`

I don't wanna use the old method like `.d.ts`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can extend any library types, by using the typescript decleration merging feature. ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html))

So this should do the job:

```
// theFileYouDeclaredTheCustomConfigIn.ts
declare module 'axios' {
  export interface AxiosRequestConfig {
    handlerEnabled: boolean;
  }
}
```

Comment: For me, this creates errors like "Property 'create' does not exist on type `typeof import("axios")'`. Ironically, the `import 'axios'` from the downvoted answer below seems to fix it.

Comment: This is because in order to properly augment a module in TS, you need to import the "target" module into the context in which you're performing the augmentation. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation

Answer (score 3):

```
// in axios.d.ts
import 'axios';

declare module 'axios' {   
    export interface AxiosRequestConfig {
        handlerEnabled?: boolean;   
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please, add some explanation to your code.

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Comment: Just in case someone tries to understand the answer. You should be creating another type file containing the above. If you paste it inside your *index.d.ts* where you have your typings it will break them.